# "Lower my standards"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

**[SOURCE](https://www.ted.com/talks/anne_lamott_12_truths_i_learned_from_life_and_writing/transcript?language=en)** (Anne Lamott - TED talk @04:56)

> - By the end I was deteriorating faster than I could ***lower*** ***my*** ***standards***
>
> what is the meaning of the phrase above?

Answer (score 2):

To **lower your standards** means to relax your criteria for what is acceptable, to make the criteria less strict, thereby making something acceptable which would not have been acceptable previously.

Comment: There is something unsatisfying about the sentence; she set out to make a comparison between the two declining elements but the syntax fell apart. But this is _ex tempore_.

Comment: I'm glad the question wasn't "What does this sentence mean?" and that it focused only on the phrase.

Comment: Yes, also i want to know the meaning of the sentence؟

Comment: There's not enough context in the snippet you've quoted to know what sort of **deterioration** is involved (physical? mental? moral?) or to know what "the end" refers to.